# How to make SIMD divisions by zero give zero? (x86-64)

Tags: floating-point, x86-64, simd, sse, divide-by-zero

I have floats that I want to divide, some of them may be zeros. How can I make it such that division by zeroes, when they happen, just return zero instead of NaN on x86-64?

I tried setting the FZ and DAZ flags of the MXCSR, to no avail. Am I misunderstanding something? Is Flush to Zero + Denormals Are Zero not supposed to make divisions by zero give zero?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>

int main()
{
    #define CSR_FLUSH_TO_ZERO      (1 << 15)
    #define CSR_DENORMALS_ARE_ZERO (1 << 6)
    unsigned int csr = _mm_getcsr();
    csr |= CSR_FLUSH_TO_ZERO;
    csr |= CSR_DENORMALS_ARE_ZERO;
    _mm_setcsr(csr);

    __m128 a = { 0 };
    __m128 b = { 0 };
    a = _mm_div_ps(a, b);

    float f[4];
    _mm_store_ps(f, a);
    printf("%f\n", f[0]); // prints out 'nan'
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/cfzPe5jcG

Comment: Is your real question about how FTZ and DAZ work, or do you actually want a vectorized division where division by exactly 0 produces 0?

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, I want to be able to divide by zeroes, and instead of NaN results I want zeros.

Comment: Do you want `0` in every case where the divisor was zero (including non-zero dividends where the result would be +-Infinity), or only in the 0/0 -> NaN case?  (Or in any NaN case, such as NaN/123?  If the latter, you could check the result for NaN, although that has worse critical-path latency than checking both inputs.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Your current answer is spot on, I want to mask off the elements where the divisor input was `0.0f`. Somehow I thought that the MXCSR could do that for me, such that any division by zero would return me zero instead of garbage. It's possible that I have divisor inputs of `0.0f`, just give me zero back when that happens. It seems like I have no choice but to mask them out myself like your answer says.

Comment: Ok.  Well keep in mind that `1.0 / 0.0` isn't "garbage" or NaN in IEEE FP math, it's +Infinity.  And if you want NaN propagation from any actual NaN inputs like `NaN / 0.0`, you'd need to check the dividend.  (But in most vectorized math, NaNs only happen due to bugs, so you only need NaN propagation while debugging.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no MXCSR setting that will do that, you'll need an extra couple instructions (`cmpps` against the divisor, and `andps` or `andnps` on the result) to mask off the elements where the divisor input was `==0.0f`.

---

Division by zero produces +-infinity, or NaN if the dividend was also zero.  There's no subnormal output to Flush To Zero.

Enabling DAZ would make `0 / subnornal` treat the subnormal as exactly `0.0f` and give you NaN instead of `0.0f` with a zero dividend.  For a non-zero normalized dividend, you'd still get overflow to +-Infinity with a subnormal divisor.

FTZ (Flush To Zero) only does anything if the result would be subnormal.  It disables gradual underflow; that's the only case where flushing happens, not other cases that would raise other FP exceptions.  DAZ (Denormals Are Zero) only does anything for subnormal (aka denormal).

Comment: You could use `blendvps` instead of `andps`+`andnps`+`orps`. The arguments to `blendvps` would be the division result and divisor, so that zero elements in the divisor replace NaN and infinity elements in the division result.

Comment: Although, on the second thought, you don't need the blend if the replacement value is zero, a single `andps` would do. `blendvps` would still be useful, though, if the replacement value is not zero.

Comment: @AndreySemashev: exactly, the replacement is zero so you only need either `andps` **or** `andnps` like my answer says, not a blend.